# "TFTP: can't read from local file.." error seen for windows impersonated admin account..

Tags: c#, windows, security, impersonation

Here is all the info that may help you in finding the root cause to the mentioned issue.

PC setup:

1. Set to WORKGROUP setting.
2. Contains both local Standard USER and local ADMIN accounts.

Case: 
1. Run a software application under Standard USER account with admin 
impersonation.
2. Contains a restricted folder that is accessible only by local admin accounts and not the standard user for security reasons.
3. The application code is written in C#.

Problem:
When System32 TFTP.exe invoked through the application Process.start(), getting the error "TFTP: can't read the local file..", where the local file is in the restricted folder.

Observation:

When the following statement is used for impersonation:
(LogonUserA(userName, domain, password, LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, ref token) != 0)

the application cannot access the restricted folder (Why? The impersonation is admin account.)

But, when (LogonUserA(userName, domain, password, LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, ref token) != 0) is used, the application can access the folder, but, TFTP.exe throws the above mentioned error where it can't read the file.

When the main application invokes TFTP.exe through Process.Start(), it starts another process. Is the impersonation lost when another process invoked from the main process?

Tried several options, like setting the Process object with domain/user/pwd info. Nothing worked.

Is anyone out there know what's missing here? Any pointers welcome.

Comment: `LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS` - clone current token - you not got `username/password` token (this parameters can be any not empty string - it not checked). with `LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE` - you always get restricted (not admin) token. `the impersonation lost when another process invoked from the main process?` - of course yes. impersonation only for thread. not affected new created process and any another threads in current process. and unclear how you impersonate at all (usually standard user can not impersonate - he have no priviledge for this)